# Update place information using google places API webservice

Tags: google-places-api

How do we update the hours information of a place that already exists in google's database.
I do see "Add places" api, but do not find any "update place" api.
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

For now the only solution seems to be deleting the place and re-adding it. But both actions will need to go through the moderation process again in order to appear in Maps (public).
If anyone else have a better solution please post